# Samsung Galaxy Tab 7.0 Plus will not enter recovery mode

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, recovery-mode

I have recently gotten a Samsung Galaxy Tab 7.0 Plus (Wifi only). I am attempting to boot it into recovery mode for the sake of rooting the device, but it is not working as anticipated. When I start the device by holding down power + vol down I see the warning screen that prompts me to press volume up to "continue", or volume down to "cancel (restart tablet)". When I press volume up, it goes to the Odin Mode screen, showing the green android robot, and the words "Downloading... Do not turn off target!!". It remains that way indefinately until I hold down the power button to turn it off. Kies is installed on my PC, and I have tried to reboot it into recovery both with it plugged in to the PC and without. If it is plugged in to the PC while it is stuck at "downloading", eventually a popup appears in Kies stating "Device not responding. To resolve the issue reboot the device." Does anyone see something I am doing wrong? Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I will answer to help anyone else. I still cannot get to recovery with only the device, but I was able to reboot into recovery and successfully root the device by using "adb reboot recovery" from the command line on my PC while the Galaxy Tab was attached to USB.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but hopefully this answer will help someone.  For the Samsung Tab 3, Tab 3 Lite, Tab 4, and many other tablets:

To get into **recovery mode**

- Hold Power button and Volume **Up** button and Menu button.
- If your device is rooted and you have ADB enabled - Type in: `adb reboot recovery`

To get into **Download Mode**

- Hold Power button and Volume **Down** button and Menu button.
- If your device is rooted and you have ADB enabled - Type in: `adb reboot download`